# Инжиниринг Базовый или Базисный?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать Базовый или Базисный Инжиниринг и почему? В проектах употребляются оба варинта.

Comment: @Ринат, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, выскажу своё негодование по поводу слова "инжиниринг". Это вопиющий варваризм, который никак не оправдывает его "технарская" подоплёка. Есть у нас слово "инженер", давно уже обрусевшее, устоявшееся в плане написания и произношения, почему бы в соответствии с этим не писать "инж**е**н**е**ринг", дабы подчеркнуть происхождение от "инженер", какое-то единство, раз уж так захотелось взять эту форму из английского?

Во-вторых, слова "базовый" и "базисный" в  целом синонимичны, как и слова "база" и "базис". В технической, экономической литературе используются и то, и другое, отличия между ними лично мне неясны, тут, видимо, во главе традиция, а не разница в значении.

Мне кажется более корректным вариант "базисный инженеринг", так как тут прилагательное имеет более однозначное значение (то есть инженеринг базиса, основы проекта), тогда как "базовый" может восприниматься как  "типовой" или "простейший", а не только "начальный".

Answer (score 0):

Оба употребляют, и оба верны, синонимичны, т.к. употреблены в значении "основа чего-то" - инжиниринг "в основном, в общем, т.е. "начальный, не детальный". Базис в третьем значении - совокупность общественных отношений (базис и надстройка).

А вот насчёт инжиниринга и инженеринга - мне, например, понятно, почему привилось иностранное инжиниринг: чтобы как раз не путать с просто инженерными работами. Понятие инжиниринг включает в себя не только разработку базовой технологической документации, но и составление перечня потенциальных поставщиков и подрядных организаций, предварительную подготовку тендерной документации; разработку процедур контроля качества и безопасности, т.е. ответственность за внедрение проекта, сдачу "под ключ" и анализ его работы. Если что-то не так, организация переделывает за свой счёт. Это более широкое понятие.

http://www.enginrussia.ru/company/interview/ingenernye_uslugi_ili_inginiring__

Comment: Не согласен. Что такое "просто инженерные работы"? Инженер — это очень широкое понятие.

Answer (score 0):

engine (n.) Look up engine at Dictionary.com
c.1300, "mechanical device," especially one used in war; "manner of construction," also "skill, craft, innate ability; deceitfulness, trickery," from Old French engin "skill, wit, cleverness," also "trick, deceit, stratagem; war machine" (12c.), from Latin ingenium "inborn qualities, talent" (see ingenious), in Late Latin "a war engine, battering ram" (Tertullian, Isidore of Seville). Sense of "device that converts energy to mechanical power" is 18c.; in 19c. especially of steam engines.
engineer (n.) Look up engineer at Dictionary.com
mid-14c., enginour, "constructor of military engines," from Old French engigneor "engineer, architect, maker of war-engines; schemer" (12c.), from Late Latin ingeniare (see engine); general sense of "inventor, designer" is recorded from early 15c.; civil sense, in reference to public works, is recorded from c.1600 but not the common meaning of the word until 19c (hence lingering distinction as civil engineer). Meaning "locomotive driver" is first attested 1832, American English. A "maker of engines" in ancient Greece was a mekhanopoios.
engineer (v.) Look up engineer at Dictionary.com
1818, "act as an engineer," from engineer (n.). Figurative sense of "arrange, contrive, guide or manage (via ingenuity or tact)" is attested from 1864, originally in a political context. Related: Engineered. Middle English had a verb engine "contrive, construct" (late 14c.), also "seduce, trick, deceive" (c.1300) and "put to torture."
engineering (n.) Look up engineering at Dictionary.com
1720, "work done by an engineer," from engineer (n.). As a field of study, attested from 1792. An earlier word was engineership (1640s); engineery was attempted in 1793, but it did not stick.

Исходя из этого все ясно с Е  в инженере. Неверное произношение.
Но так уж повелось.  
Но, тем не менее, горжусь этим, я инженер. В смысле образованный изобретатель, РАЗРАБОТЧИК,  Вопрос - чего?
В старые добрые времена писали с уточнением, инженер-механик, технолог, программист, конструктор и т.п. Слишком уж понятие стало объемным. А раньше это был мастер на все руки, вспомните Сайруса Смита. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сайрус_Смит

Инжиниринг-режет слух,  из-за ни в середине слова... да и инг тоже.
И особенно слова: базисный и базовый, типа знаю базовый английский, в пределах церковно- приходской школы, не писать, не читать -- "шпрехать" с трудом.
Говорили бы и писали тогда на английском с американскими прибамбасами, зачем русский вообще?
Маркетинг, мерчендайзер, пирсинг, ... трахтинга не хватает базисного...
Начальная инженерная проработка проекта строительства, или объекта, это слишком по-русски.
НОВОРЕЧЬ проще, тупее.

Comment: Согласна, можно было обойтись и без иностранного термина, видимо, оказалось проще заимствовать новый термин, чем аналитически объяснять суть новых отношений между заказчиком и создателем  проектной документации."Начальная инженерная проработка проекта строительства" не передаёт смысла процесса инжиниринга - предварительных исследований и проектов, генерального плана, оценки стоимости проекта, отслеживания эффективности (мониторинг)+ подготовки рабочих чертежей, технической документации и т.п.

Comment: Инженеры всем этим занимаются. Есть инженеры-разработчики, инженеры-конструкторы, ведущие инженеры, главные инженеры и так далее, которые изучают тех. задание, предлагают решения, разрабатывают их, работают на пусконаладке, диагностируют, сопровождают эксплуатацию и так далее.

Comment: Занимаются-то инженеры, но на новом уровне, который многограннее, чем "инженерные работы" старых времён - сдали объект - и работы закончены. Что-то с объектом случится - только уголовная ответственность, если жертвы, а теперь ошибку заставят переделывать за свой счёт, потому что инжиниринг включает в себя материальную ответственность за инвестиции в проект.

Comment: В старые добрые времена за крупные ошибки отвечали не деньгами, а жизнью. Утрирую конечно, но так было и долгое время вплоть до расстрела, и по-любому свобода дороже денег. А  еще негласный кодекс чести. Инженеры - мостовики при испытаниях даже и в нынешние времена под мост встают. Конструкторы самолетов сами летали и летают. И инфаркты на работе--плата.
А НИРЫ всю жизнь были  и этапы проектирования, гос испытания и сопровождение.

Comment: Так что понимание инжиниринга в таком ключе ничего нового не принесло в сферу разработки, да и в сферу администрирования. Лишь попачкало в русском языке то, что и так есть.
За разрушения с жертвами--ответственность все равно осталась.Только нынче стрелочников стало больше.За крупные аварии отвечает управляющий персонал своим местом. если стрелочника не нашли.Поменьше--спускают на тормозах, а наиболее частые и мелкие проколы спихивают за счет потребителя продукта.

Comment: Думаю, что здесь дается описание явления, которое называется "страхом к неизбежной новизне". Так хочется жить по старинке: без новых слов, без новых технологий.  Каждым делом должен заниматься специалист, а базисным инжинирингом  занимаются именно специалисты, предлагая многовариантность технических и экономических проработок, выбор оптимального решения, применение прогрессивных технологий, использование современных методов организации и т.д. Вряд ли предприятие может иметь  собственных инженеров-специалистов, владеющих подобной информацией и имеющих опыт такой работы.

Comment: Новые технологии всегда были и будут, инжиниринг не технология, это еще одно импортное название разработки, конструирования или проектирования. Все, что вы перечислили, и так входит в эти понятия, по умолчанию. 
Если это Инженеры и Специалисты, то они всегда  предлагают многовариантность технических и экономических проработок, выбор оптимального решения, применение прогрессивных технологий, использование современных методов организации и т.д.  
Этому в вузах и учат. А если попался неуч, жаль руководителей.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать термин базисный инжиниринг как более точный.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Слова БАЗА И БАЗИС - совпадают в значении "основание, основа чего-н.", но при этом слово база - многозначное  (например, овощная база, альпинистская база, материально-техническая база).

Суффикс Н  в прилагательном "базисный" также имеет значение общей отнесенности к предмету, в то время как суффикс ОВ может иметь разные значения (принадлежность, свойственность и др.)

Базовый инжиниринг можно понять как "инжиниринг (чего) базы" или как "инжиниринг, принадлежащий базе".

Comment: Как бы Вы ни философствовали по этому поводу, это термины синонимичные, зависят лишь от страны заимствования http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-496.htm  ба́за -со времени Петра I; . Через нем. Base или франц. base из лат. , до этого времени это же называлось базис-basis, греч. ( Фасмер)
Лев Успенский:БАЗА ( и базис )." Объяснять почти нечего: в греческом языке "базис" означало "основание","цоколь". Обе наши формы связаны с этим словом". http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/2/str42.html

Comment: База не во всём совпадает со смыслом образованного от этого же корня прилагательного. Базовый - исходный, начальный(базовые знания).Греческие корни слова означают основание, устойчивость. Старшее значение - ход, шаг, нога.  Производный от истоков слова смысл: база – все то, что обеспечивает движение, развитие, как и базис.Слово входит в состав многих экономических и финансовых понятий. Среди них: базовая ставка, базовый капитал, базовый индекс, базовый пункт, денежная база, монетарная база, тарифная база, ресурсная база, а инжиниринг и базовый, и базисный-начальный и обеспечивающий развитие.

Comment: Людмила, я не философствую, а всего лишь высказываю свое частное мнение, и непонятно, почему оно Вас так расстраивает. С этимологией слов я, разумеется, знакома (обычно всегда с этого начинаю). Но в данном случае ни толковый, ни этимологический словарь не подсказали мне прямого обоснования для выбора варианта. И кстати, что Вы имеете против философии? Почему нельзя рассуждать самостоятельно, но можно только цитировать словари?

Comment: Да ради бога, только не по поводу правильности терминов.Здесь мы, лингвисты, не можем просто философствовать и указывать, что более точно, что менее точно в науке ЭКОНОМИКА и в профессии инженера-строителя, как бы кто-то ни понимал значения суффиксов,но "инжиниринг, принадлежащий базе"никто не поймёт, т.к.это нелепица.Терминологию нужно просто знать и справляться о ней в справочниках и научной литературе.

Comment: Существует понятие, которое определяется термином базовый/базисный инжиниринг. Это не очень удобно, так одно и то же понятие имеет два названия, и можно подумать, что речь идет о разных предметах (а в терминологии  точность очень важна). Поэтому и требовалась филологическая консультация, которая, к сожалению, не состоялась, так как в основном обсуждался термин "инжиниринг", прямого отношения к вопросу не имеющий.